# satellite images in matlab

Tags: matlab, satellite-image

I have a satellite image in the BSQ format. I initially processed it using ENVI. Now, I am trying to read the image using Matlab's *multibandread* function.

This is the data pertaining to the image I am trying to load

```
samples = 911

lines   = 3191

bands   = 196

header offset = 0

data type = 2

interleave = bsq

byte order = 0
```

This is the code I've written to load the image.

```
I = multibandread('QUAC.bsq',[3191,911,196], ...
     'int16','0','bsq','ieee-le',{'Band','Direct',[29,23,16]});
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error using multibandread>parseInputs (line 311)
Unable to open QUAC.bsq for reading.

Error in multibandread (line 112)
info = parseInputs(filename, dims,...
```

I looked up the format for the multibandread function on this website 
http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/d/dc/LoadHypercubesMatlab.pdf

I checked the code for *parseInputs* on MATLAB, but I was unable to make any difference.

What mistake am I committing while trying to load the image?

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: @Masi I did solve the problem, I think. Given that it is well over three years now, I will have to look into what I did to solve it. I will post a solution in a few days.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit old, but it may be useful for somebody else to know the answer.

This was most likely a wrong filename ('QUAC.bsq'), or that file was not located in the current MATLAB working directory.

There is another mistake in the list of arguments that, with a valid filename, returns this error in Matlab 2015b :

```
Error using multibandread>parseInputs (line 337)
Expected input to be one of these types:

double, single, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, int8, int16, int32, int64

Instead its type was char.

Error in multibandread (line 111)
info = parseInputs(filename, dims,...
```

Replacing '0' with 0 in multibandread arguments should fix the problem, worked for me. The correct syntax is:

```
I = multibandread('QUAC.bsq',[3191,911,196], ...
 'int16',0,'bsq','ieee-le',{'Band','Direct',[29,23,16]});
```